# $G\cdot H$ with $G,H$ non-Abelian finite simple

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, nonabelian-cohomology

Can a non-split extension of one non-Abelian finite simple group by another exist?

Comment: No. The outer automorphism group of every finite simple group is soluble. Of course, the proof involves the classification.

Comment: Of course that result depends on CFSG.

Comment: On the other hand, there is quite an interesting non-split extension of the shape $(A_5)^6.A_5$, where $A_5$ is the alternating group of degree five.

Comment: @DaveBenson so? Why can’t $H$ act trivially on $G$?

Comment: If the action of $H$ on $G$ was trivial then the group would be $G \times H$.

Comment: The remaining details. Consider an extension $1\to G\to L\to H\to 1$. By the above solvability result, the natural homomorphism $H\to\mathrm{Out}(G)$ is trivial, so the natural homomorphism $L\to\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ maps into $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$. Hence $GC_L(G)=L$ ($C_L(-)$ denoting the centralizer). Since $G$ has a trivial center, $G\cap C_L(G)=\{1\}$. Hence $L=G\times C_L(G)$.